# Visual Studio 2019 Connection string to Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, connection-string, visual-studio-2019

Just downloaded Visual Studio 2019 and was playing around with it following MS tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-aspnet-core-ef-step-03?view=vs-2019)

On the setting up the database connection I left everything as default in appsettings.json it has the entry:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "AppDbContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=AppDbContext-751ed4b2-26eb-401f-82ef-a0a083ac64af;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

However when I run it I get the error message:

> SqlException: Cannot open database
>   "AppDbContext-751ed4b2-26eb-401f-82ef-a0a083ac64af" requested by the
>   login. The login failed. Login failed for user
>   'DESKTOP-PU*****\a****'. (where PU***** and a**** are my pc name and
>   username

So next I tried what I use for Visual Studio 2017 by connecting to SQL 2017 with connection string:

```
"AppDbContext": "Server=DESKTOP-PU*****\\SQL17EXPRESS;Database=AppDbContext_MSDN;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

but now get the error message:

> SqlException: Cannot open database "AppDbContext_MSDN" requested by
>   the login. The login failed. Login failed for user
>   'MicrosoftAccount\*************@hotmail.com'.

I cant recall VS2017 logging on using my hotmail account - how do I get around these problems?

Comment: please use . or (local) instead of DESKTOP-PU***** for server attribute

Comment: Thanks but still cant get it to work have tried

Server=(local)\\SQL17EXPRESS;Database=AppDbContext_MSDN;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true

and

Server=.\\SQL17EXPRESS;Database=AppDbContext_MSDN;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true

but still getting message


SqlException: Cannot open database "AppDbContext-751ed4b2-26eb-401f-82ef-a0a083ac64af" requested by the login

Comment: Do you have a database named `AppDbContext-751ed4b2-26eb-401f-82ef-a0a083ac64af` on your local server?

Comment: try `<add name="DataModelName" connectionString="data source=.;initial catalog=YourDatabaseName;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=User(sa)Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`